# Error response from daemon: ADD failed: no source files were specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dockerfile, jhipster

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
        
ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# Add a jhipster user to run our application so that it doesn't need to run as root
RUN adduser --disabled-login --shell /bin/sh --gecos "" jhipster
WORKDIR /home/jhipster

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown jhipster:jhipster entrypoint.sh
USER jhipster

ADD *.jar contourservice.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8084
```

entrypoint.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && sleep "${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}"
exec java "${JAVA_OPTS}" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar "${HOME}/contourservice.jar" "$@"
```

console:

> Step 8/10 : ADD *.jar contourservice.jar
>
> Error response from daemon: ADD failed: no source files were specified

I try to exec command docker build src/main/docker/
but in step 8, when docker try to ADD *.jar it failed.

It is my hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: First, you need to build your project with this 'mvn package' code and check next to your docker file if your jar file exists.

Comment: Yes, i execute mvn package before run Dockerfile